# proof of Triangle Removal Lemma

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, proof-writing

Where can I find a proof of the following version of Triangle Removal Lemma (or any version equal to it)?

> Let $G(V,E)$ be a graph on $n$ vertices such that it contains $\varepsilon n^3$ triangles, then we need to remove at least $\varepsilon n^2$ edges from $G$ to make it triangle-free.

Comment: Check out https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dc340/EGT6.pdf

Comment: thanks... but I'm not sure it is the same thing, because I need to prove the argument with 'at least', while they prove 'at most'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to use removal lemma to prove your claim, you can prove it using simple combinatoric argument:

every edge in the graph can participate, at most, in $n-2$ triangles. so, removing any edge will reduce the number of triangles in the graph by at most $n-2$ triangles.

If you remove $\epsilon n^2$ edges, it will reduce the number of triangles by, at most, $$\epsilon n^2 \cdot (n-2) < \epsilon n^3$$